# C++ changing object in vector doesn't work

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, trie

I want to implement a trie using a vector to store the nodes but somehow my insert method doesn't work. I've managed to build the trie data structure using a different implementation but I would like to understand why my current implementation doesn't work.

Works (not index based storing of childs/references):

```cpp
struct Trie {
   struct Trie *references[26];
   bool end; //It is true if node represents end of word.
};
```

DOESN'T WORK (index based storing of childs/references):

```cpp
struct node {
    int references[26] = {0};
    bool end; 
};
```

It doesn't work because of a faulty insert function.

```cpp
void insert_word(string s){
    node *current_node = &trie[0];
    // current_node->references[4] = 9999 WORKS! Node in Trie is UPDATED
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        print_trie();
        int letter_num = static_cast<int>(tolower(s[i])) - static_cast<int>('a');
        int next_index = current_node->references[letter_num];
        cout << "letter num: " << letter_num << " next index: " << next_index << endl;
        if(next_index == 0){
            node new_node;
            trie.push_back(new_node);
            current_node->references[letter_num] = trie.size()-1; // DOESN'T WORK! Node in Trie is NOT UPDATED
            cout << "new value: ";
            for(auto c:current_node->references)
                cout << c << " ";
            cout << endl;
            cout << "in for" << endl;
            print_trie();
            current_node = &trie.back();
        } else{
            current_node = &trie[next_index];
        }
    }
    current_node->end = true;
}
```

The problem is that when I access `current_node` as a reference to an object ob the trie vector and I change its value. The object/node in the trie vector isn't always updated. It works in the second line but further down it somehow stops working. I would like to understand why.

Here is a short debug program I wrote to simplify the problem. Here everything seems to work fine.

```cpp
    n1.references[0] = 1;
    n2.references[0] = 2;
    n3.references[0] = 3;

    trie.push_back(n1);
    trie.push_back(n2);
    trie.push_back(n3);

    node *n = &trie[0];
    n->references[0] = 10; // Tree is updated properly
    n = &trie[1];
    n->references[0] = 11; // Tree is updated properly
```

Can you help me understand why the insert function doesn't work properly?

EDIT: Minimal working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int num_words;
    int references [26] = {0};
    bool end; 
};

vector<node> trie;
int n;


void print_trie(){
    cout << "#### NEW PRINT TRIE ##### " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<trie.size();i++){
        cout << "node " << i << ": ";
        for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
            cout << trie[i].references[j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void insert_word(string s){
    node *current_node = &trie[0];
    // current_node->references[4] = 9999 WORKS! Node in Trie is UPDATED
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        print_trie();
        int letter_num = static_cast<int>(tolower(s[i])) - static_cast<int>('a');
        int next_index = current_node->references[letter_num];
        cout << "letter num: " << letter_num << " next index: " << next_index << endl;
        if(next_index == 0){
            node new_node;
            trie.push_back(new_node);
            current_node->references[letter_num] = trie.size()-1; // DOESN'T WORK! Node in Trie is NOT UPDATED
            cout << "new reference value of node: ";
            for(auto c:current_node->references)
                cout << c << " ";
            cout << endl;
            current_node = &(trie[trie.size()-1]);
        } else{
            current_node = &trie[next_index];
        }
    }
    current_node->end = true;
}



int main()
{
    node root;
    trie.push_back(root);
    insert_word("hallohallo");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: These: `node *current_node = &trie[0];` , and `current_node = &trie.back();`, and `current_node = &trie[next_index]` are a recipe for introducing a dangling pointer. Look at the loop operation. Those pointer stores can/will become invalid when/if the vector undergoes a resize due to `push_back` operation (which is clearly in your loop). Mantra: don't store pointers pointers to objects in vectors that undergo volatile sizing operations; use an *index* instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime a `std::vector<T>` undergoes a resizing operation all iterators and pointers to elements are *invalidated*. Using your mcve as an example of where this goes off the rails, consider the marked lines:

```
void insert_word(string s){
    node *current_node = &trie[0];  // **HERE
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        print_trie();
        int letter_num = static_cast<int>(tolower(s[i])) - static_cast<int>('a');
        int next_index = current_node->references[letter_num];
        cout << "letter num: " << letter_num << " next index: " << next_index << endl;
        if(next_index == 0){
            node new_node;
            trie.push_back(new_node); //** RESIZE
            current_node->references[letter_num] = trie.size()-1;
            cout << "new reference value of node: ";
            for(auto c:current_node->references)
                cout << c << " ";
            cout << endl;
            current_node = &(trie[trie.size()-1]); // **HERE
        } else{
            current_node = &trie[next_index]; // **HERE
        }
    }
    current_node->end = true;
}
```

In each location marked with `// **HERE`, you're storing a pointer to an object hosted in your vector. but the line marked with `// **RESIZE` can (and will) resize via copy/move/etc the entire vector once the capacity is reached. This means `current_node` no longer points to a valid object, is a dangling pointer, but your code is none-the-wiser and marches on into *undefined behavior*.

There are a couple of ways to address this. You could `reserve` the capacity from inception if you know it ahead of time, but for a more robust solution don't use pointers to begin with. if you enumerate via *index* instead of pointer your solution becomes the following:

```
void insert_word(std::string s)
{
    size_t idx = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        print_trie();
        int letter_num = static_cast<int>(tolower(s[i])) - static_cast<int>('a');
        size_t next_index = trie[idx].references[letter_num];
        std::cout << "letter num: " << letter_num << " next index: " << next_index << std::endl;
        if(next_index == 0){
            trie.emplace_back();
            trie[idx].references[letter_num] = trie.size()-1;
            std::cout << "new reference value of node: ";
            for(auto c : trie[idx].references)
                std::cout << c << ' ';
            std::cout << std::endl;
            idx = trie.size()-1;
        } else{
            idx = next_index;
        }
    }
    trie[idx].end = true;
}
```

Notice how all instances of `current_node` have been replaced with `trie[idx]`. And changing the "current node" is now just a matter of changing the value of `idx`, which is relevant even when the underlying vector resizes.

Answer (score 0):

that might be caused by type mismatch `int` is assigned `size_t`
try ... `= (int)trie.size()-1`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int num_words;
    int references [26] = {};   //........... int
    bool end; 
};

vector<node> trie;
int n;

void print_trie(){
    cout << "#### NEW PRINT TRIE ##### " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<trie.size();i++){
        cout << "node " << i << ": ";
        for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
                cout << trie[i].references[j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void insert_word(const string& s){
    node *current_node = &trie[0];
    // current_node->references[4] = 9999 WORKS! Node in Trie is UPDATED
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        print_trie();
        int letter_num = int(tolower(s[i]) - 'a');
        int next_index = current_node->references[letter_num];
        cout << "letter num: " << letter_num << " next index: " << next_index << endl;
        if(next_index == 0){
                node new_node;
                trie.push_back(new_node);
                current_node->references[letter_num] = (int)trie.size()-1; //....size_t  DOESN'T WORK! Node in Trie is NOT UPDATED
                cout << "new reference value of node: ";
                for(auto c:current_node->references)
                    cout << c << " ";
                cout << endl;
                current_node = &(trie[trie.size()-1]);
        } else{
                current_node = &trie[next_index];
        }
    }
    current_node->end = true;
}



int main()
{
    node root;
    trie.push_back(root);
    insert_word("hallohallo");
    return 0;
}
```